# phpseclib live console/terminal using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, ssh, console, phpseclib

I'm trying to code a live console/terminal.
For that I am using **phpseclib** library, at first I include all stuff & login:

```
use phpseclib\Net\SSH2;

include('vendor/autoload.php');

$ssh = new SSH2('127.0.0.1');
if(!$ssh->login('user', 'pass')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

$ssh->setTimeout(1);
```

after that I check for an Ajax request (*read* for display, *write* for execute):

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    if($_POST['request'] == 'read') {
        echo $ssh->read();
    } elseif($_POST['request'] == 'write') {
        $ssh->write($_POST['command']."\n");
        echo $ssh->read();
    }
    exit();
}
```

HTML markup:

```
<textarea readonly>...</textarea>
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Command">
    <button>
        Do it
    </button>
</div>
```

Some jQuery:

```
$('div button').click(function(e) {
    $('div button').text('Loading...');
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php',
        data: {
            request: 'write',
            command: $('div input').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('textarea').append(data);
            $('textarea').scrollTop($('textarea')[0].scrollHeight - $('textarea').height());
            $('div input').val('');
            $('div button').text('Do it');
        }
    });
});
```

**The Problem(s)**
every time I request cmd with *write()* it will show the Debian login message (and if I change the current directory using *cd* and after that I use *ls* it resets - because the new login I think), also im not sure how to create an interval so I get the current output continually - e.x. if I ping a website. Tried smth. like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php',
        data: {
            request: 'read'
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('textarea').append(data);
            $('textarea').scrollTop($('textarea')[0].scrollHeight - $('textarea').height());
        }
    });
}, 300);
```

Im thankful for any help!

Comment: Looks like this was cross-posted to https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/1124 ?

Comment: @neubert yes, but got just some links there, nothing so far i can work with :/

Comment: Are you still messing with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## I have done it!

I was able to do this but without SSH lib. You should be able to take this answer and work it into your existing code.

## Information First

Yes, the reason why you keep seeing the login, and why the directory changes do not persist is because you are reconnecting and creating a new session each time. Additionally, since PHP removes all resources (your SSH connection) on exit, you cannot make it persist by serialization or anything.

Basically, what you need is a bash session that stays up that you can interact with, using PHP. You can do this with `netcat` and a `fifo` and some PHP `system()` calls.

## Example with a "run command" script (which persists!):

- SSH to your server.
- Run `screen` (this is so the `netcat` command keeps running even after you logout)
- Run the following (persistently listens to port 1234 on localhost, writes to fifo, and cat's the fifo contents into a shell).

  ```
  rm /tmp/f
  mkfifo /tmp/f
  cat /tmp/f | /bin/sh -i 2>&1 | nc -k -l 127.0.0.1 1234 > /tmp/f
  ```
- Use CTRL+A+D to detach from the `screen` session (or make another SSH connection while leaving the above command running)
- Create the following PHP script and make it executable (`chmod +x`)

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/php
  <?php
  $com = $argv[1];

  $junk = system('(echo "'.$com.'") | nc localhost 1234');
  $data = system('(echo "") | nc localhost 1234');

  echo $data
  ?>
  ```

## Explanation of the script:

So, we `echo` the command you want to run into `netcat` (nc), which connects it to the other persistent `netcat` running a shell, the output of the command is written to the `fifo` but not before the current contents of the `fifo` is read write to the `$junk` variable. Next we `echo ""` and pipe that to `netcat`, which again is sent to the other `netcat` which writes "" to our fifo, only this time when the `fifo` is read it contains the result of the previous command we ran. Neat, huh?

## Example of script use:

```
    root@zim:/tmp# ./run_command.php "mkdir /tmp/stackoverflow"
    $ $ $ $root@zim:/tmp# ./run_command.php "cd /tmp/stackoverflow"
    $ $ $root@zim:/tmp# ./run_command.php "ls -al"
    total 8
    drwxrwxr-x  2 ttucker ttucker 4096 May 22 07:38 .
    drwxrwxrwt 11 root    root    4096 May 22 07:39 ..
    $ $ $ $root@zim:/tmp# ./run_command.php "touch a b c d"
    $ $ $ $root@zim:/tmp# ./run_command.php "ls -l"
    total 0
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 ttucker ttucker 0 May 22 07:39 a
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 ttucker ttucker 0 May 22 07:39 b
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 ttucker ttucker 0 May 22 07:39 c
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 ttucker ttucker 0 May 22 07:39 d
    $ $ $ $root@zim:/tmp# ./run_command.php "mkdir subdir"
    $ $ $ $root@zim:/tmp# ./run_command.php "cd subdir"
    $ $ $root@zim:/tmp# ./run_command.php "ls -al"
    total 8
    drwxrwxr-x 2 ttucker ttucker 4096 May 22 07:40 .
    drwxrwxr-x 3 ttucker ttucker 4096 May 22 07:40 ..
    $ $ $ $root@zim:/tmp# ./run_command.php "touch q w e r t y"
    $ $ $ $root@zim:/tmp# ./run_command.php "ls -al"
    total 8
    drwxrwxr-x 2 ttucker ttucker 4096 May 22 07:40 .
    drwxrwxr-x 3 ttucker ttucker 4096 May 22 07:40 ..
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 ttucker ttucker    0 May 22 07:40 e
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 ttucker ttucker    0 May 22 07:40 q
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 ttucker ttucker    0 May 22 07:40 r
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 ttucker ttucker    0 May 22 07:40 t
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 ttucker ttucker    0 May 22 07:40 w
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 ttucker ttucker    0 May 22 07:40 y
    $ $ $ $
```

## One buggy thing:

It does seem to return `$` a couple of times when running commands. This is because it still returns the `$` for the shell after a command completes. I think you could easily scrub this out though...

## Additional Thoughts / Security Concerns:

- This reeks of hackery.
- The idea of a webpage shell seems like a super bad idea.
- Remember that any other users on the system could pipe commands and into port 1234 and run them as the user you are running this script as.
- Did I mention I thought this was a bad idea?

Comment: Oh, another way to solve this is to `echo $PWD > /tmp/mypwd` after each command, and `cd (cat /tmp/mypwd)` before each command... It isn't really a persistent shell, but... it will do the trick. However, my answer is better because you don't have to wait for SSH

Comment: Oh, and about `ping!` you are going to have problems with any program that continues to run. Just always use a count flag with ping. `ping -c 10 derp.com`

Comment: You could have also made a Node.JS daemon which can be communicated with via HTTP. A bit faster and adds flexibility.